# TFS Project collection not started after DB restore

Tags: tfs-2015

We currently building a Non TFS environment. We install TFS 2015 Update 3 successfully. We create a project collection called Project 1 and create successfully. Then we copied the Tfs_Project1 database from Production environment
and try to restore using the following steps

## Restoring TFS

## 1.Stop Service

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 14.0\Tools\TfsServiceControl Quiesce

## 2.Restore DB using SQL Management Studio

## 3.Remap DBs

TfsConfig.exe remapdbs /DatabaseName:SS01\APP01;Tfs_Configuration /SQLInstances:SS01\APP01 /continue
In this step i recieved errord TF400777: Unablee to find the database for the host with name "Project1".. This collection will be marked as unavailable. Please stop this collection via the TFS Management Console

## 4.Register DB

Tfsconfig.exe registerDB /SQLInstance:SS01\APP01 /DatabaseName:Tfs_Configuration

## 5. Start Service

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 14.0\Tools\TfsServiceControl Unquiesce

## 6.Unable to start collection in Team Foundation  Admin Console.

Error: TF400783: The host "Project1' cannot be started. The host is in the process of being serviced. The servicing may have failed and needs to be restarted and completed before the host can be started

is there any best practice to restore or to import Project collection from Prod environment to non prod environment?

Comment: Did you detach the collection in the TFS admin console before taking the backup?